# Validating checkbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, checkbox

I have problem to validate multi checkbox , I want to check if the user has selected at least one checkbox. 
Im try with document.getElementByClassName but does not work

HTML:

```
<form id="formupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" name="formupload">
    <input onKeydown="javascript:validateForm();" id="txtFileName" name="txtFileName" />
    <input onKeydown="javascript:validateForm();" id="title" name="title" />
    <input onKeydown="javascript:validateForm();" id="keywords" name="keywords" />
    <input onKeydown="javascript:validateForm();" id="description" name="description" />


        <span class="niche">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="channel[]" class="css-checkbox" id="box_1">
        <label class="css-label" name="lbl_1" for="box_1">Amateur</label>
        </span>

        <span class="niche">
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="channel[]" class="css-checkbox" id="box_2">
        <label class="css-label" name="lbl_2" for="box_2">Amateur</label>
        </span>

        <span class="niche">
        <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="channel[]" class="css-checkbox" id="box_3">
        <label class="css-label" name="lbl_3" for="box_3">Amateur</label>
        </span>

<button id="btnSubmit" class="btn lbtn upBtn" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

And Here is javascript:

```
function validateForm() {
    var txtFileName = document.getElementById("txtFileName");
    var titleTxt = document.getElementById("title");
    var tagsTxt = document.getElementById("keywords");
    var descTxt = document.getElementById("description");

    var isValid = true;
    if (txtFileName.value === "" || titleTxt.value === "" || tagsTxt.value === "" || descTxt.value === "" ) {
        isValid = false;
    }

    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = !isValid;

}
```

Comment: Where are you even attempting to determine the state of the check boxes?  The JavaScript code posted only looks at some "untyped" `input` elements (which I guess default to text boxes?) but doesn't look at the check boxes at all.  (Which are invalid, by the way.  The `input` tags for the check boxes need to be closed.)

Comment: You could try `if (document.getElementById("formupload").querySelectorAll('input[name="channel[]"]:checked').length > 0) { }`

Comment: @David input elements do not need to be closed, as they may not contain any content.  In fact, the spec forbids a closing tag.

Comment: @RayNicholus: Interesting.  I didn't know that, but W3C just confirmed it.  Too bad it's past the edit window for my comment.  Either way, thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: @David You are quite welcome.  After looking at the spec again, I learned that the closing tag was actually forbidden.  I didn't recall that tidbit myself.  Just knew that it was not required.  I'm not sure if this detail is enforced in all browsers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var checkBoxes=document.getElementsByClassName("css-checkbox");

var booleanResult=false;
for(var i=0;i<checkBoxes.length;i++){
 if(checkBoxes[i].checked){
    booleanResult=true;
    break;
 }
}
if(booleanResult==false){
alert("invalid")
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7sAuK/)**

Comment: It should be if(checkBoxes[i].checked). Also, i believe it should be getElementsByTagName('input'), with a check for type=='checkbox' in the for loop.

Comment: Keep in mind getElementByClassName isn't supported by IE versions before 9.0.

Comment: @Phaedrus So it is better
`var checkBoxes=document.getElementsByName("channel[]");`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you want to target the `class` or the `name`, you could try `querySelectorAll`:

```
var form = document.getElementById("formupload");
if (form.querySelectorAll('input[name="channel[]"]‌​:checked').length > 0) {

}
// or
if (form.querySelectorAll('input.css-checkbox​:checked').length > 0) {

}
```

Of course, you could add `[type="checkbox"]` to either of those, but it seems kind of unnecessary.

`document.querySelectorAll` has better support in older browsers and is more versatile.

Of course, if you want better support than that, you could get all checkboxes, loop through them and check if they have the class, then see if there's more than one checked. For example:

```
var form = document.getElementById("formupload"),
    inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    i, cur, enoughChecked = false;
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    cur = inputs[i];
    if (cur.type === "checkbox" && hasClass(cur, "css-class") && cur.checked) {
        enoughChecked = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (enoughChecked) {
    // At least 1 checkbox is checked
}

function hasClass(element, className) {
    return !!~(" " + element.className + " ").indexOf(" " + className + " "));
}
```

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll